# delete button in PHP website behaving like static when clicked

Tags: php, sql, forms, button

i have a simple delete button in PHP which uses simple SQL query to delete the data from database, I have used the following code:

```
$myid = $this->uri->segment('3');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $ret = mysqli_query($con,"delete * from smart_category where name='$myid'");
    header("Location: https://cloudclassmate.com/jewelry-catalogue/admin/viewcategory");
}
```

```
<div style="margin-left:38%" class="clearfix">
    <a href="https://cloudclassmate.com/jewelry-catalogue/admin/viewcategory"> 
        <button type="button" class="cancelbtn bemine">Cancel</button></a>
    <form action="" method="post" ><button type="submit" name="submit"  class="deletebtn bemine">Delete</button></form>
</div>
```

the problem here is if I click the delete button, its not responding, nothing is happening. the button is like static. can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here

Comment: Is there any Javascript involved in this page that might be preventing the submission or clicking the button?

Comment: @El_Vanja not at all,

Comment: @El_Vanja if i am adding action in form, its going to that action URL, but when I remove action URL button behaving like static

Comment: That is strange. Empty action (or if you completely omit the action) should submit to the same page.

Comment: @El_Vanja emptied it and removed action also, still button is static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any Javasscript is not involved, than just put form action.
Also send `myid` in the request or in URI.
please see below:

```
<div style="margin-left:38%" class="clearfix">
    <a href="https://cloudclassmate.com/jewelry-catalogue/admin/viewcategory"><button type="button" class="cancelbtn bemine">Cancel</button></a>
    <form action="abc.php" method="post" ><button type="submit" name="submit"  class="deletebtn bemine">Delete</button></form>
</div>
```

Comment: whwre to send myid?

Comment: and in action what url should i give?

Answer (score -1):

You should add an action url/path to where your PHP file is located and add a Method to your form. Also, I noticed you deleting an entry where "name" is equal to $myid please check if that is correct.

```html
<div style="margin-left:38%" class="clearfix">
   <a href="https://cloudclassmate.com/jewelry-catalogue/admin/viewcategory"><button type="button" class="cancelbtn bemine">Cancel</button></a>
  <form action="url-to-server.php" method="post" >
    <button type="submit" name="submit"  class="deletebtn bemine">Delete</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
$myid = $this->uri->segment('3');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $ret = mysqli_query($con,"delete * from smart_category where name='$myid'");
    header("Location: https://cloudclassmate.com/jewelry-catalogue/admin/viewcategory");
}
```